# Как выполнить какое-то действие, если в коллекции найдется элемент с соответствующим полем?

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream, java-8

Как выполнить какое-то действие, если в коллекции найдется элемент с соответствующим полем?

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
...
add values
...
String customer;

for (item:items){
    if (Objects.equals(item.getId(), "123123123")){
        customer="admin";
        break;
    }
}
```

Как это будет выглядеть с использование java 8, stream api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`Stream::anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
boolean contains = items
    .stream()
    .anyMatch(item -> Objects.equals(item.getId(), "123123123"));
String customer = contains ? "admin" : null;
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/TVEK9q)

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще вариант с `Optional` для разнообразия:

```
String customer = items.parallelStream().map(Item::getId)
        .filter("123123123"::equals).map(s -> "admin")
        .findAny().orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если принять во внимание то, что Id однозначно определяет соответствующий ему Item и, кроме того, в данном случае имплементит Comparable, то для оптимизации можно воспользоваться структурой данных [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) и хранить идентификаторы в ней.

```
List <Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
TreeSet<String> setOfIds = items.stream().map(item -> item.getId()).
                           collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
String customer = setOfIds.contains("123123123") ? "admin" : null;
```

Такой подходит позволяет ускорить процесс поиска в коллекции до O(logN).